# Process hundreds of thousands of records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have Ruby on Rails powered application.

In database, I have about half-million records on companies.
Each record for company is for some month,
and has two fields - PRICE and PERFORMANCE.

User enters values (criteria)
for PRICE to be considered "good",
and value for PERFORMANCE to be "good".

So each record can be evaluated as

- "bad price, bad performance"
- "bad price, good performance"
- "good price, bad performance" or
- "good price, good performance".

What is the fastest way 
to loop through all records, 
and mark it as belonging to one of four segments?

As result, application shows chart - counts per segment per month.

Comment: Is there a reason this "bad price, bad performance" data needs to be stored in the database?  You already have that information in the form of the PRICE and PERFORMANCE fields.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it via SQL right in the database will definitely be faster than going trough ActiveRecord. Something like:

```
UPDATE records SET type = 1 WHERE price = 'bad' AND performance = 'bad';
```

If the queries run too slowly and/or you need to run them often consider adding a multicolumn index on the two columns `price` and `performance`.